# VueJS 1.0.8 - Remove object from array based on index

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am in the process of upgrading a project to Vue 1.0. I have an array of objects in the following format:

```
data: {
shifts: {
            '43' : {
                userId: 43,
                name: 'Frank'
            },
            '90' : {
                userId: 90,
                name: 'Martha'
            }
        }
}
```

Prior to 1.0, to remove an object, I would use `this.shifts.$delete('90')` to delete that object. This no longer works and it is unclear to me what the replacement is. I have also tried `this.$remove(this.shifts, '90')`, `Vue.$remove(this.shifts, '90')`, etc.

Also, `$add` was deprecated in favor of `$set` but I cannot figure out how to add a new object (such as `'95: { userId: 95, name: 'John' }`) with `$set`.

Very frustrating, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this,

```
// to set
Vue.set(this.shifts, '95', {userId: 95, name: 'John'})
// to delete
Vue.delete(this.shifts, '95')
```

http://codepen.io/pespantelis/pen/PPLJKP

Comment: Ahh you beat me to it by a matter of seconds ;) Apparently I overlooked this in the docs - especially the part where a `$` is no longer part of it. Thanks!